# JavaFX 2.2 create video from set of images

Tags: video, javafx, video-processing

I want to create and export video file that is created from a set of images and a mp3 file.

Can I do this with new JavaFX API in java 7 or 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create videos using JavaFX 8 APIs.

JavaFX 8 has only video decode capabilities and no video encode capability.

Comment: Thanks, now I know that I will have to search for java encode jar :)